# SQL INNER JOIN subquery using derived tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is an example of a zoological park.

There are three tables: employee, animal and animal_employee, a n:m table to establish the relationship between the two.
I want to query the employees who deal with the same animal. But the way I'm doing it I can only output the id numbers. I want to output the actual names that can be found on the tables: employee and animal.

This is what I have for now:

```
select distinct a.animal, a.employee, b.employee
from animal_employee a, animal_employee b
where a.animal = b.animal and a.employee > b.employee
```

Comment: Post the tables schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

I think I would do this with a CTE:

```
with ae as (
      select ae.*, e.name as employee_name, a.name as animal_name
      from animal_employee ae join
           employee e
           on ae.employee = e.?? join  -- don't know what is used for the `JOIN` here
           animal a
           on ae.animal = a.??         -- don't know what is used for the `JOIN` here
     )
select a1.animal_name, ae1.employee_name, ae2.employee_name
from ae ae1 join
     ae ae2 
     on ae1.animal = ae2.animal and ae1.employee < ae2.employee;
```

Your question is unclear about the table structures.  The `??` is the for the columns to be used for the joins.

You only need `select distinct` if the result set might have duplicates -- and that would only happen if your tables had duplicates (which is unlikely).

Comment: Just remembered to share a small correction. On "e.name as animal_name" it's "a.name". Anyway, it's working great thanks again.